# Windows Phone development in Visual Studio 2012 RC

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Today Microsoft released Windows 8 Release Preview and visual studio 2012 rc. I'm a Windows phone developer. What dev tool I have to use for create my apps in Windows 8 rp?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 express download page, it is mentioned like

"**A Visual Studio 2012 Express product for Windows Phone will be available in conjunction with the next Windows Phone release. Until then, you can continue to use Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone to create Windows Phone apps."**

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/express

Answer (score 6):

The Windows Phone 8 SDK is out now, for those that are still reading this. It includes the 7.1 and 7.1.1 as well, and all runs within Visual Studio 2012. You can get it here:

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Comment: Just a sidenote: Windows 8 is required for installation of the Windows Phone 8 SDK, so if you're still on windows 7: Sorry, no cake for you...

Comment: Yeah utter garbage, no chance anyone will be developing for Windows Phone 8 if they are forcing developers to use Windows 8 OS, madness!

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 8, install VS2010, the Windows Phone SDK, and don't forget the 7.1.1 SDK update that fixes problems with Windows 8.

Comment: its that I get VS2010 free from my school otherwise I killed someone